# How to write an ANTLR4 grammar to parse matching html tags

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I wrote a simple parser to try to learn how ANTLR4 works on an HTML-style language with matching tags. For example, if there is a tag

```
<p> ... </p>
```

I thought it should be matched with a rule:

```
p: '<' 'p' CLASS_NAME? '>' tag_block '<' '/' 'p' '>' ;
```

This seems rather heavy because I have to manually write each rule this way if it can contain everything else. Is there a generic way to write a rule that for each kind of tag that can contain others, the angle brackets before and after have to match? Or do I simply have to write it for each one:

```
p: '<' 'p' CLASS_NAME? '>' tag_block '<' '/' 'p' '>' ;
div: '<' 'div' CLASS_NAME? '>' tag_block '<' '/' 'div' '>' ;
canvas: '<' 'canvas' CLASS_NAME? '>' tag_block '<' '/' 'canvas' '>' ;
```

Is it possible to write a generic compound tag like:

```
compoundtag: '<' ('p' | 'div' | 'canvas') CLASS_NAME? '>' tag_block '<' '/' ( MATCHING EARLIER NAME???) '>'
```

I'm sure I have made many more mistakes, so here is the complete grammar file:

```
grammar simple_grail;

prog: tag_block ;

tag_block: (tag)*;

/* root definition of any tag in Grail */
tag:
    p | div | canvas | rect | button | txt | textlit;

p: '<' 'p' CLASS_NAME? '>' tag_block '<' '/' 'p' '>' ;
div: '<' 'div' CLASS_NAME? '>' tag_block '<' '/' 'div' '>' ;
canvas: '<' 'canvas' CLASS_NAME? '>' tag_block '<' '/' 'canvas' '>' ;
rect:
     '<' 'rect' CLASS_NAME?
     'x' ASSIGN_COORD 'y' ASSIGN_COORD 'w' ASSIGN_COORD 'h' ASSIGN_COORD
     '/>' ;
button:
    '<' 'button' (CLASS_NAME)? (NAME)? 'text' ASSIGN_TEXT '/>' ;
txt:
    '<' 'text' 'x' ASSIGN_COORD 'y' ASSIGN_COORD '/>' ;

textlit:
    TEXT?
    ;

CLASS_NAME: [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]* ;

ASSIGN_COORD: '=' [0-9]+ ;

name: 'name' '=' NAME ;

NAME: [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]* ;

ASSIGN_TEXT: '=' ('"' [^"]* '"' | '\'' [^']* '\'');

TEXT: [^<]+ ;
```

I want to parse a first little program:

```
<p>text goes here</p>
```

I expect that textlit should match the text, and for a tag that surrounds text like p, that
I should overwrite the exitTextlit() method and exitP() to decide what to do. If I intercepted enterP() I would not yet have the text inside. Is that right?

There is a warning that I could match the empty string, and I know that will create an error if I skip blank space, but I don't understand how a program is supposed to match:

```
<p></p>
```

If textlit cannot be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) 2 things going wrong:

1. `textlit` should not match an empty string, because `textlit` is being repeated by `tag_block: (tag)*;`
2. ANTLR's regex syntax is slightly different: instead of doing `[^<]+` (which matches one or more of the characters `'^'` or `'<'`), do this: `~[<]+` (which matches one or more characters other than `'<'`)

When you fix these points, you will see the following tokens being created for the input `<p>text goes here</p>`:

```
5 tokens:
  1    null                           '<'
  2    TEXT                           'p>text goes here'
  3    null                           '<'
  4    TEXT                           '/p>'
  5    EOF                            '<EOF>'
```

As you can see, `p>text goes here` is not correct. A way to solve this is by using a [lexical mode](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/dev/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexical-modes). You can have a look at the HTML grammar in the ANTLR repo: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/html

I always just test through a small Java class, but if you use `TestRig`, be sure you're working with recently generated parser classes and compile them.

#### 1. generate new classes

```
java -jar antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar simple_grail.g4
```

#### 2. compile generated classes

```
javac -cp .:antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar *.java
```

#### 3. run `TestRig`

```
java -cp .:antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig simple_grail prog simple0.grail
```

This will produce the error:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input '<' expecting <EOF>
```

which is expected, given `TEXT` matches too much.

Comment: Wow, that's really astounding how small the grammar is for all of HTML. Thanks for that.

Comment: Just one more thing though on this answer, my test isn't working:

java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig simple_grail  simple0.grail

just hangs?

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: see the above, I am running the TestRig on the grammar (generated with no warnings per your corrections) on file simple0.grail which contains <p>test</p> and it hangs

Comment: @Dov updated my answer about TestRig. I see you forgot the parser rule to start with: it should be `java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig simple_grail prog simple0.grail`